# In SQLAlchemy, any performance difference between .first() and [0]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, slice

Any difference between

```
a = session.query(Accounts).filter(Accounts.key = 4).first()
```

and

```
a = session.query(Accounts).filter(Accounts.key = 4)[0]
```

?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Tried a few cases and didn't find any significant differences, but I'm new to SQLAlchemy and relatively new to Python. Thought someone might know of some edge cases or general wisdom (along the lines of avoid using eval...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mata indicated and pointed to the source code, there is no difference in the execution path of the two. In fact, you can also enable SQL logging by setting `echo=True` when you create an engine, and you will see that the both SQL statements are exactly the same (some sort of `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ....id = ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?`)

But, if the `Accounts.key` is actually a primary key, the best way to get a persistent instance by the primary key is to use the [`Query.get`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get) method, which will generate `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ....id = ?` and it should be good enough. I assume it is not going to be faster, but is much cleaner.

Comment: Beautiful. I hadn't noticed the Query.get method yet. And it will be faster if the object is already in memory.

Answer (score 4):

apparently, there isn't much difference between useing [`__gettitem__`](http://hg.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/file/c9d2c02b964d/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#l2023) or [`first`](http://hg.sqlalchemy.org/sqlalchemy/file/c9d2c02b964d/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#l2140)

hint: both of the above calls basically return the same as:

```
query = session.query(Accounts).filter(Accounts.key = 4)
a = list(query[0:1])[0]
```

Comment: Apparently... But can you provide any proofs?

Comment: i've linked to the relevant source passages. what more proof do you need? just in case i've added a short explanation of what it does to my answer.